# Web analytics tool for share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My client is looking to install Web Analytics tool for sharepoint 2013 and this tool should not send data out of the network. it should be using for instance google analytics since it wont be compliance with governance of security. please let me know if you know of any tool to do analytics of user activity on share point site with out sending data out side of the network.

Comment: We use HarePoint Analytics. https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointAnalyticsForSharePoint/Default.aspx

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Harepoint is not work for us since it is using google analytics behind

Comment: I am not aware of that. It has its own internal database and IIS log importer. What makes you think it uses Google Analytics? It reports stats by named user and that is a violation of the free Google Analytics ULA, so I don’t see how that is possible because we have not purchased GA.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at standart Sharepoint analytics tools. 
For search popularity reports go to `Site Settings` and find `Popularity and Search` or just go to `/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSiteCollection`.

Also use Health Reports for in CA `Monitoring-View health reports` or `/_admin/HealthReport.aspx`

For visits and traffic analytics you can try Piwik.